# qmake: How to link a library twice?

Tags: c++, qmake, circular-dependency

I need to link the `libA.a` library in my `qmake` file twice:

```
LIBS = -lA \
       -lB \
       -lA \
       -lC \
       -lD
```

but `qmake` is removing the first `-lA` while running `g++`. What should I do?

Comment: Just curious; why would you need to do that?

Comment: @NikosC. Cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell qmake to disable merging of all LIBS flags with:

```
CONFIG += no_lflags_merge
```

However, this will result in all duplicate libraries to not be cleaned up. This shouldn't matter in practice though.

Alternatively, you can trick qmake so that it doesn't find the duplicate libary; since it only matches strings and doesn't really parse the library flags, you can do:

```
LIBS += -lA -lB -l A -lC -lD
```

Note the difference between `-lA` and `-l A`. This makes sure that qmake doesn't see those flags as equal, even though from the compiler's point of view, they are equal, since the compiler does actual command line argument parsing while qmake does not.

Comment: What it produces is: `g++ -lA  -lB  -lA -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc/lib -o TableView main.o mainwindow.o customsqlmodel.o model.o helper.o cdrlistmodel.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_customsqlmodel.o -lC -lD -L/opt/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/gcc/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Sql -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread`

Comment: But it does not work because `-lA  -lB  -lA` is right after `g++`. If I move them before `-lC -lD` (by hand), the program compiles successfully: 
`g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc/lib -o TableView main.o mainwindow.o customsqlmodel.o model.o helper.o cdrlistmodel.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_customsqlmodel.o -lA  -lB  -lA -lC -lD -L/opt/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/gcc/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Sql -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread`

Comment: Both solutions are great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -( -lA -lB -)
```

?

Edit: did you try

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -( -lA -lB -lC -lD -)
```

What this syntax does is that it will resolve all the depencies between the libraries, even if they are somewhat recursive (A::stuff needs B::stuff needs C::stuff needs A::stuff)

Comment: Could you please include the `C` and `D` libraries as well?

Comment: I am getting this error: `/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make: *** [TableView] Error 2`

Comment: And this is the last command executed with syntax error: `g++ -( -lA -lB -lC -lD -) -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc/lib -o TableView main.o mainwindow.o customsqlmodel.o model.o helper.o cdrlistmodel.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_customsqlmodel.o   -L/opt/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/gcc/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Sql -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread`

Comment: What if you try `-start-group -lA -lB -lC -lD -end-group` ?

Comment: Add `QMAKE_LINK=ld` to your qmake.pro

Comment: `QMAKE_LINK` seems obsolete. [Shouldn't it be](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-link-shlib-cmd) `QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB_CMD`?